# SaveFileDialog button events in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a `SaveFileDialog` in my WPF Project.

If the `SaveFileDialog` is closed via the red 'x' in the corner, I want the dialog to close and the user to be returned to the main application.

However, if the `SaveFileDialog` is 'canceled', I want the entire application to close.

The only issue I am having is knowing if the user has pressed the red x or the cancel button. They both evaluate to false in the code below.

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text file (*.txt)|*.txt";
var dlg = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
if (dlg == true)
{
    //When the user presses save
    File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog.FileName, rowList);
    ExitApp();
}
else if (dlg == false)
{
    //This occurs when red x or cancel is pressed.
}
```

Is there any way to distinguish between the two in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is short and simple:
"no"

See Microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms614336(v=vs.110).aspx) here

Answer (score 0):

It is not so simple, but you can do it by using [hooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx) and the [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

First of all we need a class for registering and unregistering our hook:

```
public class WinHooker
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(int idHook);

    private delegate int HookProc(int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private HookProc hookDelegate;
    private int hookHandle;
    private bool wasClosedButtonPressed;

    private static WinHooker instance;

    private WinHooker()
    {
    }

    public static WinHooker Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new WinHooker();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public bool WasClosedButtonPressed
    {
        get
        {
            return wasClosedButtonPressed;
        }
    }

    public void Register()
    {
        wasClosedButtonPressed = false;
        hookDelegate = this.HookProcHandler;

        hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(5,
            hookDelegate,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId());
    }

    public void Unregister()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookHandle);
        hookHandle = 0;
        hookDelegate = null;
    }

    private int HookProcHandler(int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            if (nCode == 8 && wParam == 0xF060)
            {
                wasClosedButtonPressed = true;
            }
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

As you can see I used 5 as the first parameter for the `SetWindowsHookEx`, since it correspond to the **WH_CBT** value (refer to the [SetWindowsHookEx page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx)). Moreover the values in the method `HookProcHandler` (i.e. `nCode == 8 && wParam == 0xF060`) can be retrived from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx).

Now let's use our class in the code:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

WinHooker.Instance.Register();
saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
WinHooker.Instance.Unregister();

if (WinHooker.Instance.WasClosedButtonPressed)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Oh my God! What have you done??");
}
```

As you can understand `WasClosedButtonPressed` is set to true just if the user closes the dialog by clicking on *the red 'x' in the corner*. Otherwise it is false.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide that. I hope it can help someone else as I've decided not to go to the trouble.